# Using mysql_real_escape_string() instead prepared statement in IN operator

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, sql-injection

I'm in a situation where I can't mix named and positional parameters in my PDO prepared statement. It's a long story but to simplify I decided to just ditch prepared statements when using `IN` operator.

E.g., use plain `WHERE column IN (1, 2, 3)` instead of `WHERE column IN (?, ?, ?)`.

To ensure data is still safe, can I just use `mysqli_escape_string()` instead?

E.g.,`WHERE column IN ('.mysqli_escape_string($a).', '.mysqli_escape_string($b).', '.mysqli_escape_string($c).')` ?

In a nutshell, I want to know if `mysqli_escape_string()` is a good replacement for prepared statement in my use case?

Edit: replaced mysql_* with mysqli_*

Comment: Since the `mysql_*` extension no longer exists ... I'd say definitely not.

Comment: No, it is not good.

Comment: Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string?rq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: It is not safe even if you were to use `mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $thing)`

Comment: @CD001 Thanks for pointing that out. I have replaced the question with `mysqli_`

Comment: Are you actually using integers in your query? Use `intval`, I'm pretty sure SQL injection isn't getting around that.

Comment: This is for a wrapper function for PDO so it is not always integers

Comment: *"This is for a wrapper function for PDO..."* - which rather begs the question as to why you're abstracting an abstraction class..?

Comment: If wrapping PDO will mean that you lose the ability to use prepared statements then don't do it.

Comment: @CD001 Ok here's the "long story": I made a query builder class long ago that used PDO name parameters in the prepared statements. Now I needed to use `IN` statements and realize I couldn't mix named and positional params together. 100% of the query builder used named params, unfortunately it appears I can't use named params in `IN` statements, only positional params. It's clashing together so I must ditch positional params.

Comment: Can you design your query builder to create a series of named parameter placeholders like `:inparam1`, `:inparam2`, `:inparam3`, ...